# Delete extra page from PDF used for my resume

Tags: pdf, openoffice

I use OpenOffice.org to make my résumés and cover letters and there's always an extra page at the bottom that forces me to have to copy all of the contents of it to a new document.

How can I remove or delete that extra page at the end?

I'm using OpenOffice 3.3.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Does the extra page show up when you Print Preview? If not, you could use a PDF Printer instead of saving to a PDF.

Comment: Why don't you try to solve the actual problem with the empty page at the end?

Comment: It's in OpenOffice, and it doesn't go away even when I press delete, backspace whatever it is! I've turned on the non-printing characters, and it's STILL THERE.  I've been using Wordprocessors all 31 years of my life.  The extra page will not go away.  There are alot of invisible tables in the layout.

Comment: @iglvzx I use the mail merge service to generate documents from a template..hmmm

Comment: Well I'm quite embarrassed at this point but, there was a cell at the very bottom of the resume where I used to write "References available upon request", and it looked like just the bottom of the page; but it wasn't!  It was a cell in the table that spanned all the columns above. I deleted it and it solved the problem. :p But I'll pick iglvzx's answer as it looks to be the most helpful should anyone else look at this.

Comment: Those two extra tags are not needed in the system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever I'm faced with the old extra blank page in Microsoft Word or other word processors, I do one of the following:

### A. Get rid of the blank page

1. Move the cursor to the end of the document. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> until you remove all trailing hidden objects or whitespace. *(As mentioned by [@Desingh](https://superuser.com/a/429018/100787))*
2. Set the font size for the last line to `1` or smaller.
3. Decrease the page's bottom margin to stop the overflow of content.

### B. Use a virtual printer

1. Using your favorite [virtual printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software), print the document selecting a range of pages. For example, if your content is 3 pages, but the 4th page is blank, print pages `1 - 3`.

Since your target format is PDF, I would just jump to option B. Simply print the non-blank pages to a PDF and you're done. :)

Comment: Also look for pesky rows that span all the columns in your table, that may be hiding at the bottom of the page.  When you delete them the extra page will go away.

Answer (score 3):

Before exporting as a PDF, bring the cursor to the last line of content pages, and press the **delete** key until your last empty blank page is deleted or removed.

This is often the cause of extra pages appearing when printing or exporting to PDF.

Comment: If that worked I wouldn't be here asking the question.

Comment: @leeand00 are you using any templates ?

Comment: Yes, it's a template, I use it with a MySQL database and some macros I wrote to send out resumes and cover letters to prospective employers.

Comment: @leeand00 nice.Even me too faced the same problem with my template long time before.Have you tried without template?

Comment: Well I suppose I have, I copy all of the tables in the document, to a new document, one at a time...but it would kind of defeat the purpose of the template don't you think? Well to be fair it's already doing that.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote man, it sounded like you were trying to be a wise guy, I guess you weren't.

Comment: @leeand00 It's ok ,instead of downvote we should always try to suggest or correct the mistakes of users .

Answer (score 0):

"Also look for pesky rows that span all the columns in your table, that may be hiding at the bottom of the page. When you delete them the extra page will go away."

Thanks for the tip, Leeand00. I had an extra blank page showing up in Print Preview and printing after an invoice form I'd developed in Calc. After fiddling with a bunch of things, I discovered it was a column spanning cell near the bottom of the page. It wasn't even all columns, just about 70% of them. When I reduced how many columns it spanned, (resplit the cells then remerged) the extra page vanished.

The ones higher on the page didn't matter, just the one in the last inch.

Comment: Welcome to superuser!   Is this really an answer?

Comment: @David, the best way to show that a question or an answer has been helpful is to upvote it. When you have a bit more reputation points, you can also add a comment explaining what in particular was helpful.